# How to start a Kafka-Streams Pipeline by Topology using Quarkus

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

I am following the [Quarkus Kafka-Streams tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams) and can't quite understand how a pipeline can be started.

In the tutorial the `org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder` is used to build a `org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology` that describes the pipeline. The method that builds the Topology is annotated with `@Produces`. In this [cheat sheet](https://lordofthejars.github.io/quarkus-cheat-sheet/) it's described that this is sufficient to run a Kafka-Streams pipeline. In the tutorial an http-endpoint is exposed additionally. That's not required in the service I'm currently implementing. Also in the example the provider method is never called explicitly. When I start the application without the endpoint the pipeline is not started.

In [this tutorial](https://quarkus.io/blog/kafka-streams-applications-with-quarkus-and-microprofile/) the pipeline is instantiated explicitly with a topology. But here properties have to be set manually and configuration is not taken from the `quarkus.kafka-streams.<something>` properties.

The question is: How can I use Topology builder from the first tutorial to start the pipeline described by it? Optimal case would be that the configuration from `quarkus.kafka-streams.<something>` is automatically applied.

Using:

- `Java OpenJDK 11.0.8`
- `Quarkus Version: 1.8.0.Final`

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem: No guarantee for complete correctness. Just want to share what solved my problem.

Most important is to use the right `@Produces`. `javax.enterprise.inject.Produces` is necessary to be used for the `Topology` producing method. `javax.ws.rs.Produces` can be used additionally to define the MediaType of the output, but is not mandatory:

```
    @javax.ws.rs.Produces( MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN )
    @Produces
    @AlternativePriority( 1 )
    public Topology buildTopology() {
        ...
    }
```

An instance of `Kafka Streams` is automatically built by the framework on start-up. All you need to run your pipeline is the following:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class YourApplication {
    private final KafkaStreams streams;

    public NasDistributorApplication( final KafkaStreams streams ) {
        this.streams = streams;
    }

    public void onStart( @Observes final StartupEvent startupEvent ) {
        streams.start();
    }

    public void onStop( @Observes final ShutdownEvent shutdownEvent ) {
        streams.close();
    }

}
```

Annotating the `Topology` producing method by `@AlternativePriority( 1 )` might be necessary to tell `quarkus` to use this method to build the `Topology`. I don't know the internals of the framework but what I suspect that a default Topology is used and `@AlternativePriority` gives a higher priority to the custom method than the default `Topology`